# XFCE Build Error xdt-csource.1

Tags: macos, bash, unix, gcc

I'm trying to build xfce4-dev-tools on macOS Monetary. to build and install xfce4 desktop environment. im a total noob when it comes to building c/c++ programs.

Following the steps -

1. cloned the repo,
2. added the dependencies noted by xfce.org
3. added them to the path.
4. ran `./autogen.sh` as mentioned (no error)
5. ran `make`

```sh
bash-3.2$ make
Making all in docs
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl xdt-csource.xml
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl
warning: failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl"
cannot parse http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl
make[1]: *** [xdt-csource.1] Error 4
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

what I found out was that `linux-doctools` is missing and I'm quite lost on an alternative to this lib.

also don’t ask me why I'm trying to install a DE on macOS. this should be possible as XFCE should work on nix platforms.

Comment: Your only chance of getting something like that to work is to install a package manager such as MacPorts or Homebrew.

Comment: i already have brew. brew or macports dont have a lib called `linux-doctools`. since its only for linux. but i found an alternative `xorg-docs` which did solve my issue and complied fine

Answer (score 1):

the issue was that i was missing `xorg-docs` package

isued homebrew to install this

```
brew install xorg-docs
```